# Fresh install of EC2 but can't install tasksel

Tags: ubuntu

I have a fresh instance of Ubuntu 12.04 on EC2. I am trying to install a LAMP stack, but I get this error when trying to install taskel

```
 Invalid operation tasksel
```

Any ideas how to add this to my packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a newbie of the highest order :O

Just in case anybody else googles this error, make sure you have typed all of the commands in correctly.

```
 apt-get tasksel
```

This is where I went wrong, I left out the `install`

I wanted to delete this out of embarrassment... But I think somebody else might make the same mistake...